# Call SAP Transaction ME33K with VBA Code. How?

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I am desperately looking for a code to call an agreement out of vba in ME33K in SAP.

I have the agreement number, so I want to this number to be called in ME33K and pop up the SAP GUI.

Is there a way to do it? Can someone provide a code?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with VBS from SAP itself (and not with VBA from Excel):

Go to the script recdorder: ALT+F12 > "Script Recording and playback", press the recording (red) button

Perform all you actions: go to your YSD033 screen, pull the variant, run the report, save it in Excel, close transaction.

Then stop recording.

The script (a VBS program) will be saved in your default SAP directory (but you can change this location esaily).

To run the script either play it from SAP (ALT+F12, etc except that instead of recrding it, play it) or you can also run it from Windows (if SAP is open) by double clicking the vbs file.

- Mario Rappi on Feb 26, 2010 7:18 PM

http://scn.sap.com/thread/1619517